# Join two array A and B in MATLAB and generate array C with format A,B

Tags: matlab

I am trying to join two arrays named time and heartRate. I want to join them as time, heartRate form and use it a Stream to my Program. Currently, I am generating 3 values for each matrix as follows

```
 heart_rate = 50 +(70-50) * rand (3,1)
% hist(heart_rate)

 startTime = 1 ;
 endTime = 3;
 time = startTime + (0:endTime-1)*1;
 disp(time)

 % joined = vertcat(heart_rate, time)
 %  disp(joined)
```

the output is as follows

[image]

Right now I am not able to join them as one matrix is 1*3 and other is 3*1 {this is what I think}

Want output like

```
 1,56.80
 2,50.5135
 3,53.4728
```

Suggestions are highly appreciated, Thanks in Advance

Comment: take transpose of `time` and horizontally concatenate with `heart_rate`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by the help of @Sardar Usama. The new code is as follows

```
 heart_rate = 50 +(70-50) * rand (3,1)
% hist(heart_rate)

 startTime = 1 ;
 endTime = 3;
 time = startTime + (0:endTime-1)*1;
 disp(time)
 newTime = transpose(time)

  joined = horzcat( newTime,heart_rate)
%  disp(joined)

dlmwrite('C:\Users\amar-admin\Desktop\abc.rtf', joined, 'newline' , 'pc')
```

The output in File is as follows

[image]